# Failed to fetch URL Error in Yocto for gnu-config-native

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

When giving the bitbake command,
bitbake gnu-config-native

Getting the fetch error.

### The poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb

```
SUMMARY = "gnu-configize"
DESCRIPTION = "Tool that installs the GNU config.guess / config.sub into a directory tree"
HOMEPAGE = "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git"
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "GPL-3.0-with-autoconf-exception"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://config.guess;beginline=7;endline=27;md5=b75d42f59f706ea56d6a8e00216fca6a"

DEPENDS_class-native = "hostperl-runtime-native"

INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1"

SRCREV = "5256817ace8493502ec88501a19e4051c2e220b0"
PV = "20200117+git${SRCPV}"

SRC_URI = "git://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git;protocol=https;branch=master \
           file://gnu-configize.in \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
UPSTREAM_CHECK_COMMITS = "1"

CLEANBROKEN = "1"

do_compile[noexec] = "1"

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/gnu-config \
           ${D}${bindir}
    cat ${WORKDIR}/gnu-configize.in | \
        sed -e 's,@gnu-configdir@,${datadir}/gnu-config,g' \
            -e 's,@autom4te_perllibdir@,${datadir}/autoconf,g' > ${D}${bindir}/gnu-configize
    # In the native case we want the system perl as perl-native can't have built yet
    if [ "${PN}" != "gnu-config-native" -a "${PN}" != "nativesdk-gnu-config" ]; then
        sed -i -e 's,/usr/bin/env,${bindir}/env,g' ${D}${bindir}/gnu-configize
    fi
    chmod 755 ${D}${bindir}/gnu-configize
    install -m 0644 config.guess config.sub ${D}${datadir}/gnu-config/
}

PACKAGES = "${PN}"
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir} ${datadir}/gnu-config"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

```
-----------

ERROR:
```

### WARNING: gnu-config-native-20200117+gitAUTOINC+5256817ace-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git;protocol=https;branch=master, attempting MIRRORS if available

### ERROR: gnu-config-native-20200117+gitAUTOINC+5256817ace-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'git://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git;protocol=https;branch=master')

--- ANY IDEAS??

How to solve this issue? I tried adding and removing protocol values. commit hash etc..

Comment: Did you try to use "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git" instead of git://?

Comment: Yes. The issue was solved after i removed git and directly given https as protocol.

Comment: What exactly did you changed? When I try to set "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git", I get more and worse errors about the configize.in later.